# Where is the auction house in Diablo 3 for the PS3?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I have been hearing about this auction house for a while now.Where is it in Diablo 3 for PS3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The console version(s) of the game never launched with an auction house and the PC version had it removed because Blizzard felt that it took away the core focus of the game (there were also some exploits that flooded trillions of gold into the game out of nowhere).

They ultimately felt that Diablo, at its core, was about killing monsters, exploring dungeons and earning loot from killing - not playing a virtual market.

It's no longer in any version of the game and will not make a return.

Sources:
http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/8796520380

http://www.polygon.com/2013/5/8/4311002/blizzard-takes-diablo-3-auction-houses-offline-after-gold-dupe-bug

Comment: Not sure what your source is, but it wasn't removed because players hated it.  *Blizzard* hated how it took the focus away from killing stuff to find items.

Comment: @Frank Even the slightest introspection of your assertion shows how silly it sounds. Blizzard ultimately only cares about what's best for their sales figures. The (Real Money) Auction House made them money, so the team's decision must have come down to "We will make MORE money by getting more sales of our expansion by shutting down the Auction House than we will from the fees we charge in it." That kind of business decision ONLY makes sense if players are unhappy because of the Auction House.

Comment: @Frank "Despite overwhelming player complaints that the Auction House went against the spirit of the game, Blizzard insisted that it was a necessary feature." -[Escapist Magazine](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/news/view/122980-Blizzard-Admits-Diablo-III-Auction-House-Was-a-Mistake), "With the auction house in D3, it largely became a matter of pouring over what was on offer and dropping a big chunk of gold on it, making the whole process just boring." - Commenter on [Rock Paper Shotgun](http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2014/03/19/diablo-iii-blizzard-online-auction/)

Comment: @Frank Blizzard has mastered the PR skill to the extent many important people dream of it. *Sure it was them who hated the AH, and not players*. You should've seen [the official AH shutdown video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijCgKciMIE4) Of course they've come to hate it because of so much negative feedback from the players!

Comment: @All Yes, because haters are more vocal than those that like something.  *That's how it works*.  Personally, I thought the AH made it way too easy to find upgrades.  I **sincerely** doubt the veracity of "popular demand", however.

Comment: Blizzard production director John Hight, "it became increasingly clear that despite the benefits of the AH system and the fact that many players around the world use it, it ultimately undermines Diablo's core game play: kill monsters to get cool loot," he added. "With that in mind, we want to let everyone know that we've decided to remove the gold and real-money auction house system from Diablo III." http://www.gamespot.com/articles/diablo-iii-auction-houses-closing-march-2014/1100-6414544/

Comment: I've edited the response to include more facts and sources.  Let's also not forget that because of the RMAH - more than a few people resorted to botting to try and "hit the jackpot."

Answer (score 20):

There isn't one. There was only ever an auction house for the PC, but even that was recently [shut down by Blizzard](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/blizzard-pulls-the-plug-on-diablo-3-s-infamous-auction-house/1100-6418372/).